# Securely pass ID param in URL rails

Tags: ruby, security, url, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I have a link like this:    `http://www.somesite.com/s/bkucoj?i=#{@client.id}`.
How do I make sure, that client's id will be passed securely (hashed/encrypted), and not just naked number?

So the goal is to get something like:

`http://www.somesite.com/s/bkucoj?i=f1nSbd3bH34ghfAh12lcvzD`

instead of

`http://www.somesite.com/s/bkucoj?i=12`.

How can I achieve it?

And what's more, I would also like to ensure, that on the other end the client ID is gotten correctly
Thank you!

Comment: This is a futile effort to provide security to your application. You cannot securely encode identifiers. It doesn't help against replay attacks. Also, links cannot be shared. If you just want to obfuscate the id, then go ahead and use any hashing algorithm.

Comment: I am new to these things. Yea, my goal is just to make sure, that there is no situation, when someone manually changes the client's id.

Comment: You can use a [message authentication code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) to verify its authenticity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this would be to add an extra column (non-null, unique) to your User model, which is randomized upon the User creation.

```
before_create do
  self.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
end
```

Then you can use `uuid` to identify the user instead of id.

Naturally you will need to modify all your existing user when adding this column.

### Implementation details

Your migration needs to have 3 parts. Firstly you need to add a uniq, **nullable** column uuid to `users` table. Then, you need to loop over your existing customers and populate this column. After it you can make the column not-nullable. It would most likely look like this:

```
class Blah000000000 < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save { self.uuid ||= SecureRandom.uuid }
  end

  def up
    add_column :users, :uuid, :string, unique: true
    User.all.each &:save!
    change_column :user, :uuid, string, unique: true, null: false
  end

  def down
    remove_column :users, :uuid
  end
end
```

Comment: hey man, huge thanks for update! Last question(I assume answer is "NO", but to make sure): when I'll run this migration on production, won't it trigger my after_create callbacks (which is undesirable)?

Comment: @andreydeineko - since migrations defines it own User class, your "default" class wil never be loaded (as constant_missing hook will not be triggered). Hence any callbacks defined there are undefined for this migration - this is quite a common pattern to deal with data-changing migrations.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an extra parameter which is the HMAC or digital signature of the id. The recipient can verify that id has not changed.